# is it possible to monitor folder using java code?

Tags: java, monitoring

is there anyone know how to monitor a folder using java? or anyone could gave me a point that how could i start this. here's my thought about it.

> start a thread to scan the folder changes,which could be create,delete,update files in this folder or something else happen,like last updated.
>   but in this case, you have to control thread loop. if this thread loop is not controlled well,then it would be a waste of cpu and may cause a fatal problem.

or,is there any framework or some demo code to do this ? hope we could find a better way to do this. thank u very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought is not bad.

To monitor a folder in java, the usual way is to control it in a separate thread using a loop.
In order to save CPU, you can use a tempo (check every n seconds).

Then, to notify a change from this thread, you can use the ["Observer" design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: yeah,i know this look should be taken good care of. check folder every n seconds will do it well,but how should i determine such a seconds,because this code would be run for different CPU and different OS. that's not easy if i want to save CPU and other stuff. but,thanks ur reply.

Answer (score 13):

JDK7's java.nio.file package has a [`WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to support file change notification. You can use it to monitor a directory for changes. This uses native facilities where available, otherwise it uses a primitive mechanism such as polling. [Here](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/08/java-7-watchservice-for-file-change.html) is a post on it.

For now, you can try [jpathwatch](http://jpathwatch.wordpress.com/), which is an implementation of the `WatchService` interface and uses native OS functions, instead of polling.

Comment: i think i have to wait for a long time for this,cuz my current jre is jre6.

Comment: i've checked over this WatchService, it's great but only pity that it would be only available after jdk7.

Answer (score 1):

The pure Java way would be to spun off a thread that polls the directory and tracks changes.

A more efficient way would be to write an OS specific library (You'll probably have to do it in C or C++) that can use OS specific tools to obtain a notification (via a callback into your Java code), and call it via JNI

Comment: good idea.but if i use OS specific library that means my app will not be able to run in different OS.

Comment: True. You could code it in such a way that if you're running on an OS where you have a library the code uses it, otherwise it defaults to a purely Java solution. In fact, as mentioned in other answers, this is what happens in Java 7

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. There are some libraries doing the polling for you such as:

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/filemonitor.html that is free and http://www.teamdev.com/jxfilewatcher that is not free

"*Ideally, you would like to avoid polling and have instant notification of changes. To do this would require OS-specific JNI code to hook into the native file system. This would also require high privilege.*"

Comment: via JNI that means to write cross platform code for java,it feels not right to me.

Comment: jxfilewatcher is not free. i think maybe we could find an open source software or library to do this. if there's not,i will write it.

Comment: The first link I sent is a free one I think