# in java,how to watch multiple directories

Tags: java, watch

i want to monitor the multiple folders whether new files are added in the folders.
if files are added in folder,i want to get he name of the file.
 How to do this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096404/is-there-a-sophisticated-file-system-monitor-for-java-which-is-freeware-or-open-s and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810790/is-it-possible-to-monitor-folder-using-java-code

Answer (score 3):

Theres a component called [File Monitor](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html) in the [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/) [IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library. I Think it's just what you're looking for.

Comment: The File Monitor component no longer exists. It is now the FileAlterationMonitor.

Answer (score 1):

please try this ,

```
for(;;){

    System.out.println("START MONITORING  **************");


    Path faxFolder = Paths.get("E:\\activiti\\monitor\\m1");
    Path faxFolder2 = Paths.get("E:\\activiti\\monitor\\m2");
    WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    faxFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
    faxFolder2.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);


    boolean valid = true;
    WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
    for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
        WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
        if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
            String fileName = event.context().toString();
            System.out.println(fileName);

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: For me the event.context() only contains a relative path for the changed file. How to get the absolute one, especially when watching several directories on the same WatchService? Running on Ubuntu 22 LTS/java-17-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 0):

I compared the two different approaches of the Java [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) and commons-io [FileAlterationMonitor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationObserver.html).

As it is written already in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-watchservice-vs-apache-commons-io-monitor-library), the WatchService does not require polling. It can block a thread until events are available.
On the other hand the FileAlterationMonitor uses a thread for polling and if needed notifies all registered listeners.

From the above one could conclude that using the WatchService is more performant. However the performance is implementation specific. As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) says for platforms that do not offer event based notification a polling may be implemented. So there is just a chance that WatchService is more performant, but as we move to modern filesystms which all support events the chances are growing.

There is another caveat with WatchService: it watches exactly the path you register for. There is no recursive operation. While you could now register all the subdirectories that get created to watch them too, the WatchEvent emitted by the WatchService only carries a relative path. With that you would not know which of the several directories you are watching actually produced the event.

Not so the commons-io solution. As that communicates the changes as java.io.File objects, each of the events contains the full path. Even more, once you watch a directory, also changes in subfolders are detected without additional effort.

With that the decision when to use what might be:

- Use WatchService if you have one directory/a shallow hierarchy to look for changes.
- Use FileAlterationMonitor if you have many directories or deep hierarchies to watch.